# How do I use 'IF STATEMENT…' while making a dropdown select with C# (Selenium WebDriver)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am new with Selenium. I have a dropdown field that will always have something selected and I am looking for a way to say if I run a test and the dropdown selected a value, next time I run a test I want the webdriver to know that the previous value is there and then replace it with a new value. This is what I have written but it does NOT work:

```
 IWebElement element = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("requestedby"));
        var selectElement = new SelectElement(element);                

        if (_driver.FindElement(By.Name("requestedby")).Equals("ALLCAPS"))
        {
            new SelectElement(element).SelectByValue("NOCAP");
        }
        else if (_driver.FindElement(By.Name("requestedby")).Equals("NOCAP"))
        {
            new SelectElement(element).SelectByValue("ALLCAPS");
        }
        else
        {
            new SelectElement(element).SelectByValue("NOCAP");
        }


        //_driver.FindElement(By.Name("$btn_save")).Click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to get current value use `.SelectedOption.GetAttribute("value")`

```
IWebElement element = _driver.FindElement(By.Name("requestedby"));
var selectElement = new SelectElement(element);                
var currentValue = selectElement.SelectedOption.GetAttribute("value");
// for current Text
// var currentText = selectElement.SelectedOption.Text;

if (currentValue.Equals("NOCAP"))
{
    selectElement.SelectByValue("ALLCAPS");
}
else
{
    selectElement.SelectByValue("NOCAP");
}
```

Comment: This can be simplified further by removing the entire first `if`. The result is to set it to "NOCAP" which is the same as the final `else` so it can be omitted. I changed the code to demonstrate. Feel free to revert if you don't approve.

Comment: @JeffC but there are more than two values in the dropdown

Comment: @SeleniumNewGuy Understood but if you follow the logic of what was there, the end result is the same... just less code. You might be better off picking a random value from the dropdown (and verifying that it's not the same as what you started with). That will give you better test coverage, if that's something you are looking for.

Comment: But I thought that’s what I did

Answer (score 0):

You can go through this [tutorial](https://www.programiz.com/csharp-programming/if-else-statement), sample code is pasted below for reference.

```
using System;

namespace Conditional
{
    class IfElseStatement
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int number = 12;

            if (number < 5)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is less than 5", number);
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0} is greater than or equal to 5", number);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("This statement is always executed.");
        }
    }
}
```